# How to create transparent frameset?

Tags: html, css, frameset

I want to create a page with 3 frames in a frameset.

My `Home.html` is the main page, with 3 frames, which is `Header.html`, `Announcement.php` and `Footer.html`.

```
<frameset rows="10%,*,5%" noresize frameborder="NO" FRAMESPACING="0" scrolling="NO" >
   <frame src="Header.html" scrolling="NO">
   <frame src="Announcement.php" name="container">
   <frame src="Footer.html" scrolling="NO">
</frameset><noframes></noframes>
```

Inside the `Header.html`, I defined the style of the html to transparent inside the `Frame.css`. This same to the others 2 frames as well.

```
html
{
    background-color : transparent;
}
```

But the background of the `Home.html` does not display. But when I remove the `frameset`, the background is displayed.

I uploaded it to [here](http://anonynewbie.site11.com/IMS/Home.html).

So how can I solve this problem?

Edit :

Based on [this](http://code.google.com/p/doctype-mirror/wiki/FrameAllowtransparencyAttribute) page, is the `allowtransparency` attribute browser dependability?

Solve :

I'm tried to view the page with Mozilla Firefox, it seems like working with `allowtransparency` attribute, but when I view the page using chrome, IE9 and Opera 12, it's didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
<frame allowtransparency="true" ...>
```

Comment: Isn't `allowtransparency="true"` is for iFrame?

Comment: `<frame src="Header.html" scrolling="NO" allowtransparency="true">`, is it something like this? But it's still not working.

Comment: Try to apply it also for frameset?

Comment: For me, it's only work on Mozilla Firefox 15, I tried with Chrome, IE9, and Opera 12, the other 3 browsers did not display any background.

Answer (score 0):

Try settting

```
<frame allowtransparency="true">
```

http://www.webreference.com/js/tips/010209.html

Comment: Isn't `allowtransparency="true"` is for iFrame?

Comment: Based on this page, is it `allowtransparency` attribute only apply to Opera browser?
http://code.google.com/p/doctype-mirror/wiki/FrameAllowtransparencyAttribute