# making the iframe transparent

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create transparent frameset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357654/how-to-create-transparent-frameset)

I am trying to make the iframe trasparent but it showing white color in my firefox browser. I have used the following code for the iframe

```
<iframe id="frontimg" src="slider/slide.html" width="950" height="370" border="0" scrolling="no" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

And in my desired html file i have put this code in head tag for styling:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html,
    body {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: there is no such color code `transparent`

Comment: I am not saying transparent color, but i am trying to make the iframe transparent.means, until it is loading image it becomes transparent for me.

Comment: that one is for the frame tag, here i am discussing about iframe tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't style iframes from the outside. Unless the content inside the iframe have no background color, you are out of luck. If it's inside your own domain, you may set the background transparent if it's being called from inside an iframe (in your iframe head):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 if (window!= window.top) { // inside iframe
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
   // or document.body.style.background = 'none';
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

In Firefox you need to start with none in the background:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background: none transparent;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I tried this solution also but it doesn't seems to work for me.

Comment: Did you also use "background" instead of "background-color"?

Answer (score 0):

Document is By Default White. Setting Body To Transparent and IFRAME to transparent will still show you white color. You can't make the document as a whole transparent! You can Make Elements On a Document to be Transparent.