# How do I make all white in an HTML container transparent?

Tags: html, iframe

I have an HTML container that displays another webpage. This webpage *supposedly* has a transparent background, but it is displaying as white in the container. This is the code I have implemented in the HTML container:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!-- BODY {background:none transparent;}-->
</style>

<body STYLE="background-color:transparent">

<iframe src="MY URL" width="100%" height="100%" style="border:none" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I apologize if this is completely off, this is literally the first thing I have ever done with HTML. I've just been cribbing code from my searches in the hopes that something will work.

Anyway, this displays the background as white, though the webpage I am referring to has a transparent background. Any insight you have into this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: ummmm.... If there's no color defined, transparent is defaulted to white lol Transparent is not a color after all.

Comment: I understand that I need to allow transparency in the iframe, then make the background transparent separately, but how do I do that? Again, I'm very much a beginner here, so try to make your response as "dumbed down" as possible.

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065959/making-the-iframe-transparent

Comment: I ran across that and tried it at one point, but only added that code to the HTML container, not the document I'm trying to display. I think I understand what I need to do with it then, so I'll just have to tinker with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to the HTML document you are trying to display? If so try adding this within the head tags

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 if (window!= window.top) {
   document.body.style.background = 'none';
 }
</script>
```

If you are unable to edit the source code for the HTML doc you are trying to display, you will be unable to change the background to transparent by using an iframe.

Comment: Hmm I was afraid of that. I do have access to it, but do not have the ability to edit the source code for various reasons outside my control. I appreciate the answer though.